# Active Record Querying RoR double condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following schema/relationship on my RoR app

```
|Merchant| (1-->n) |Credit      | (n-->1) |User          | (1-->1) |Merchant   |
|--------|         |------------|         |--------------|         |-----------|
|id      |         | user_id    |         |id            |         |id         |
|Name    |         |merchant_id |         |merchant_id   |         |Name       |
                                          |isMerchantUser|
```

Imagine you are logged in as a Merchant User, as a Merchant User you should only be able to see Credits that have merchant_id that matches with yours. And when you go to a User profile page you want to display all the credits awarded to a User that are related with your User.merchant_id

Take into account the following:
- Authentication system: devise. You can use the current_user method
- The query is placed on the user#index controller

The following query only works to show credits given by the logged in Merchant User, but if I go a to User profile page, I would like to restrict to show only credits given to THAT User.

```
@credits = Credit.find(:all,:conditions=>{:merchant_id => current_user.merchant_id(&:merchant_id)})
```

I am trying to do something like this...

```
@credits = Credit.where(merchant_id = current_user.merchant_id)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

This is what I did:

user#index controller

@user = Credit.where( :merchant_id => current_user.merchant_id).group(:user_id).sum(:amount)

So I got the users that have an associated credit with that merchant, group the records by User and got the sum of the amounts given to that User.